# Meaning of STORE AS in nested table in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested-table

I referred many examples of "Creating a SQL Type Corresponding to a PL/SQL Nested Table" such as

```
           CREATE TYPE CourseList AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(64);
           CREATE TABLE department (
                name     VARCHAR2(20),
                director VARCHAR2(20),
                office   VARCHAR2(20),
                courses  CourseList) 
                NESTED TABLE courses STORE AS courses_tab;
```

I referred many materials regarding this but I am not getting what is purpose of storing courses into courses_tab. Where will this courses_tab use? Please help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`courses_tab` is used to name the physical table which stores the data for the nested table. You can find it by querying `dba_nested_tables`. The column `table_name` will have the value `'COURSES_TAB'`. In addition, you can get the structure of the table by issuing the command `DESC COURSES_TAB`.